# Google Chrome Extension POST to AWS DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to set up a simple Google Chrome Extension that will pop up a form. 
The form will collect first name, last name, career title, and other informations when the user uses the extension on a particular page.
Upon submit of the pop up form, the form will reach API Gateway that trigger Lambda to write data to DynamoDB.

I can't seem to find any documentations/guides/tutorials around how to connect Chrome Extensions to AWS services.

I was wondering if I setup a React Chrome Extension, and then install AWS Amplify. Upon build by Chrome, will the AWS Amplify work..?

Comment: Are you proxying to DynamoDB from API Gateway, or are you triggering a Lambda that writes the data to DynamoDB?

Comment: I would like to reach API Gateway that trigger Lambda to write data to DynamoDB. 

I was reading into AWS SDK for Javascript in the browser.

Answer (score -1):

> I can't seem to find any documentations/guides/tutorials around how to connect 
>   Chrome Extensions to AWS services.

From AWS perspective Chrome Extension is the same as real user, web site or any other client. Depending on a technical stack of you extension, you can use AWS API or SDK inside your extension to work with AWS.